# How to prevent Angular from resetting Text Area value after (click) event?

Tags: html, json, angular

I'm receiving some raw JSON from a server which contains data extracted from a PDF, below is an extract from the JSON.

```
{
"ServiceOfSuit": {
    "text": "This insurance shall be governed by and construed in accordance with the Revised Code of Washington (RCW). Each party agrees to submit to the exclusive jurisdiction of any competent court within the United States of America.\n\nNMA 1998 (24/04/86) Service of Suit Clause: A.N.O. Attorneys (or their Nominees) 211 Main St\n\nOlympia\n\nWashington (WA) 99999, USA"
},
"RecordingTransmittingAndStoringInformation": {
    "text": "Where Broker XYZ maintains risk and claim\n\ndata/information/documents Broker XYZ may hold\n\ndata/information/documents electronically."
},
"NoticeOfClaims": {
    "text": "This insurance shall be governed by and construed in accordance with the Revised Code of Washington (RCW). Each party agrees to submit to the exclusive jurisdiction of any competent court within the United States of America.\n\nNMA 1998 (24/04/86) Service of Suit Clause: A.N.O. Attorneys (or their Nominees) 211 Main St\n\nOlympia\n\nWashington (WA) 99999, USA"
}}
```

My plan was to create a form in which text would be within a text area and the label would be the key. Thus allowing someone to edit the value and later save it, updating the JSON. I managed to do in HTML using the code below. Where **originalRules** holds the raw JSON and **keys** is a pipe which helps me iterate through the JSON and returns the key and value.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let rule of originalRules | keys">
    <ng-container *ngIf="rule.value.text">
        <label style="display: inline-block" [innerHTML]="rule.key"></label>
        <textarea rows="6" class="input" [id]="rule.eltID" [innerHTML]="rule.value.text"></textarea>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

### The Problem

The problem i'm having is that whenever I edit the text area and then click a button on the page (the button could even have an empty on click method) it resets the values. Is there a way in which I could prevent this?

Just a side note, I am aware that I could parse the JSON in typescript and put it into an array, therefore making it easier to iterate through and generating the text areas, and this does work. However I would prefer to do all this work in HTML as I have more complicated scenarios in which I have more nested data in my JSON which could be arrays, that I plan on displaying in different ways.

Sorry for the long question and thanks in advance.

### Edit

More relevant parts of the code incase it helps:

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value, args: string[]): any {
    const keys = [];
    for (const key in value) {
        keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
}}
```

Comment: Can you please check if your page submitted and thus reloads on click?

Comment: @DicBrus The page does not reload or submit. I made sure the button type was "button" and made sure it was not submitting anything.

Comment: Can you show you your whole code including the component?

Comment: @GaganPrajapati I added the code for the Pipe in case that helps, the rest of the code is largely irrelevant and simply does other things.